# nginx sending 301 redirects to http instead of https

Tags: nginx

Running `nginx 1.11.6` in a Docker container

I have a number of redirects of the form `/old/content` -> `/new/content`

However nginx is redirecting visitors that come in from `https` to `http`:
`https://example.com/old/content` -> `http://example.com/new/content`

I have a redirect rule to redirect all `http` traffic back to `https` but this creates a redirect chain, which I'm trying to eliminate.

Is there a way to force nginx to leave the protocol portion of the url alone?

Here is a sample of my config:

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types 
    text/plain text/css text/js text/javascript text/xml
    application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript
    application/xml application/xml+rss
    application/x-pdf application/pdf;

rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 404 /404;

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

location /old/content {
   rewrite ^/.* /new/content permanent;
}

location /old/content2 {
   return 301 /new/content2;
}

location /old/content3 {
   return 302 /new/content3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifed your nginx configuration locally with `nginx:1.11.6`, this is a working version:

```
error_page 404 /404;

server {
    listen 80;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /tmp/ssl.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /tmp/ssl-key.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    location /old/content {
       rewrite ^/.* /new/content permanent;
    }

    location /old/content2 {
       return 301 /new/content2;
    }

    location /old/content3 {
       return 302 /new/content3;
    }
}
```

Note that:

- `return 301` is recommended over `redirect` when you want to redirect traffic from http to https
- In your use case, it's advised to separate two server blocks, one for http and the other for https